# How do I call a Java applet from a button onclick?

Tags: java, applet

I need to pass parameters between Java applet and Html by input data into textbox
and click button. Because it must input data and past to applet in the first place, 
but how to slow down the applet ? I used to try using inner html , but it's failed.
Is there any idea for this question?

Answer (score 0):

You could use netscape package. This documentation on this is found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html). I have used this myself at times. Works on chrome, IE both windows and mac. Safari can also be tricked to work, but needs some workarounds.